# Google News Box, Open News Page in New Window/Tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have attached a [Google News Box](http://www.google.com/webelements/#!/news) on one of my pages.

Right now, if the visitor click on the news, they will leave my site and go to the news site.

I'm wondering is it possible to insert `target="_blank"` somewhere so the news is loaded in new window/tab.

Note: the link is inside the google's iframe. so I was thinking if i can somehow to create the on-click event on-top of the google iframe while grab the it's url.

```
<iframe frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 border=0
style="border:0;margin:0;width:928px;height:100px;" 
src="http://www.google.com/uds/modules/elements/newsshow/iframe.html?
rsz=large&format=728x90&q=Internet%20Retailng%20Aus&element=true" scrolling="no" 
allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Solution:

1: please refer to alfro's answer.

2: code below using the [api](http://code.google.com/apis/newssearch/newsshow/)

```
 google.load("elements", "1", {packages : ["newsshow"]});   
         function onLoad() {
            var options = {
                "linkTarget" : "_blank"             
                         }   
                  var content = document.getElementById('news');
                  var newsShow = new google.elements.NewsShow(content,options);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find in [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/newssearch/newsshow/) google.search.Search.LINK_TARGET_BLANK.

It's what you need. If you put your code would be easier to give an example.

EDITED

It's a little messy, but so does google [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#news_show_via_iframe):

Page A:

```
<head>...</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <iframe height="90px" width="728px" frameborder="0" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scrolling="no" src="pageB.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

Page B (google):

```
<iframe height="90px" width="728px" frameborder="0" marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scrolling="no" src="http://www.google.com/uds/modules/elements/newsshow/iframe.html?rsz=small&q=Foreclosure,Mortgage Refinance&format=728x90"></iframe>
```

Comment: do you mind provide an example to do that via the api way as opposed to the iframe i'm using (edited question)

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. I ended up going with apis (edited on question) as it has some additional feature that I'm looking for, but your answer works nearly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google abandoned "newsshow". It had been deprecated for a long time but a few weeks ago newsshow just stopped working. I had to scramble to build a replacement for my sites.

Here is a Google News RSS replacement that in many ways is better:

http://www.gooplusplus.com/news-frame-guide.html

(BTW, links from the news stories are automatically opened in new tabs/windows.)

See this forum thread:

http://hypercube.us/forum/index.php?topic=1501.0